# GET DIAGNOSTICS after calling a function

Tags: postgresql

I have a plpgsql procedure I am calling which has fairly simple logic.

Within the procedure, I want to continually call a function until no more rows are being inserted by the function. The function adds rows to a table iteratively from another table until the other table has no more rows to be added. I was considering using `GET DIAGNOSTICS` for this.

The function I am calling sometimes has two different inserts, dependent on certain clauses. It roughly follows this logic:

```
create or replace function func_name(_id bigint) returns void as
$$
declare
q text;
begin
select format($q$
with insert_data as (
    --removing logic
)
insert into table(col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4,col_5)
select 
   --removing logic
from insert_data i
on conflict on constraint ssm_unique do nothing;
$q$,
--removing these for now
) into q;

execute q;

if (certain_threshold > 0) then
   --do another insert into a different table
end if;
```

I know I can add row_count to the above for each step by adding something like `get diagnostics inserted = row_count;` after the execute query command is called but is there a way I can get a row_count from the procedure? I could in theory get the row_count after both inserts, then add them, and return the value but I was thinking there may be a better way to do this.

The procedure looks like this:

```
create or replace procedure proc_1(_id bigint) as
$$
declare
returned bigint;
begin

loop
   perform func_name(_id);
   get diagnostics returned = row_count;
   exit when returned = 0;
end loop;

end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

So essentially, if neither of the two inserts actually add any rows then return a value of 0 as row_count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the function as `RETURNS bigint` rather than `RETURNS void` and return the number of inserted rows, as found with `GET DIAGNOSTICS` inside the function.